# matlab matrix sizes miss match

Tags: matlab, matrix

I cannot match the sizes of the matrix . I am trying to simulate an Em wave moving in a medium with conductivity segma . The problem is when i try to plot the E and H fields , it gives me an error ( the matrix sizes miss-match). I have tried to change the values , but still no output . If someone help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance

```
segma=5
f=1000
m=2
w=2*pi*f ; % Omega
Eo= 8.854187817*10^12; %vaccum permitivity of air
y=(1+1i)*sqrt(pi*f*Eo*m*segma); % definning gamma
a=real(y)% definning alpha
b=imag(y);% defining beta
s=1/a;%skin depth
n=(1+1i)/segma*s;%characteristic impedance
vp=w*s; % phase velocity
lambda= 2*pi*s; % wavelength
t=0:1:100;                           % Time for analysis
z=0:1:100;                           % Range of Space under analysis
Ex=exp(-z*a)*cos(w*t-z*a); % assuming one component in the x-direction  propagating in the +z direction . Also we have assumed E+=1
Hy=Ex/n; % Assuming one component in the y-direction 
subplot(2,1,1)
plot(z,Ex,'g');
xlabel('z(metres)');
ylabel('Ex(E)');
title('Plane wave propagation in free space medium');
subplot(2,1,2)
plot(z,Hy,'r');
xlabel('z(metres)');
ylabel('Hy(H)');
```

Comment: Hi @ahmed, I'm just wondering whether I have solved your problem. If I have, can I kindly ask you to accept the answer as this will close your question as well as give me credits? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code:

`Ex=exp(-z*a)*cos(w*t-z*a);`

`exp(-z*a)` gives you a 1-by-101 matrix and `cos(w*t-z*a)` gives another 1-by-101 matrix. When [element-wise multiplication](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/times.html) is intended, you need to add `.` before `*`.

So the fix is:

`Ex=exp(-z*a).*cos(w*t-z*a);`

[image]

Comment: Thank you , but  i am facing a new problem . The plot function is ignoring the imaginary parts , i do not need the matlab to ignore them.

Comment: @ahmed I'm not sure how you would like your graph to be, but try this `plot(z,real(Hy),'r',z,imag(Hy),'r');`.

Comment: Thank you very much , The magnetic field (H) when plotted must be out of phase from  the electric field (E)  due to the imaginary part contained the charac. impedance n. When matlab ignores the imag. part they appear in phase with each other  . The solution you have offered me plots the H as two lines which is incorrect . Thank you

Comment: @ahmed I'm still unclear about what your plot should look like. I'm not familiar with your application. What will you do to the imaginary part of H? do you add/multiply it to the real part? Do you mind to explain more?

Comment: @ahmed If you're facing a new problem, ask a new question. Questions on SO are intended to address a single problem, not to be open-ended discussions of all of the problems you encounter in developing your code.